# How to add perpendicular spout to cylindrical water faucet main body

Tags: modeling

I'm really new to 3D-modeling so I apologize if this is a really simple concept, and I also apologize if this is the wrong place to ask a question like this.

I'm trying to model this water faucet: [image: Water faucet]

And I currently have: [image: My model of a faucet without spout]

I'm stuck on how to proceed with the perpendicular spout section. Is there a way to do it without creating another object and then using bool union?

[image]

Comment: Using Boolean would be probably worst idea. Could you please upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ?

Comment: @LukeD I added it to the main post.

Comment: Basically you only need to extrude part of the mesh, then remove some faces and rebuild desired shape. I cannot give you answer today, but if nobody else make it, I'll make one tomorrow.